# How to get data from TextField inside a kv file using Python code?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am new to KivyMD and I am presently stuck with a problem. The problem is how to get data from a textfield inside kv string. I am using Builder to load the string. The code is given below.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivymd.toast import toast

Window.size = (300, 500)

kv = '''
ScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title : 'Feed'
            right_action_items : [['magnify', lambda x:x]]

        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name : 'home'
                icon : 'home'
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        OneLineListItem:
                            text : 'feed no: 1'
                        OneLineListItem:
                            text : 'feed no: 2'
                        OneLineListItem:
                            text : 'feed no: 3'
                        OneLineListItem:
                            text : 'feed no: 4' 

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                id : 'create'
                name : 'create'
                icon : 'pen'
                MDTextField:
                    id : title
                    hint_text : 'Document Title'
                    size_hint_x : None
                    width : 200
                    pos_hint : {'center_x' : 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.7}
                MDTextField:
                    id : body
                    mode : 'rectangle'
                    hint_text : 'Document Body'
                    size_hint_x : 0.7
                    pos_hint : {'center_x' : 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.3}
                    width : 250
                    multiline : True
                MDIconButton:
                    pos_hint : {'center_x' : 0.92, 'center_y' : 0.05}
                    icon : 'sticker-check-outline'
                    
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name : 'saved'
                icon : 'upload'

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                icon : 'account'
                name : 'profile'
'''

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Feed(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Cyan'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '200'
        screen = Screen()
        main_screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        screen.add_widget(main_screen)
        return screen

    def show_popup(self):
        toast('Published successfully')
        pass

Feed().run()
```

I want to get the data from TexFields with ID's, 'title' and 'body' when the IconButton is pressed. Can somebody please help me solve this problem !

Answer (score 0):

first, I'm not sure why you use a Screen as root, to then put a ScreenManager into it, you could just as well use your ScreenManagaer as root, or put it in another layout, while it's not problematic to use a Screen like this, it shows a misunderstanding of the role of Screen, which is to be used inside a ScreenManager.

To the main point:

You do not show what code you want to run when the IconButton is pressed, but you say you want this code to access these ids, and i assume you want to call the `show_data` method of the app.

The easiest way for that is simply for the MDIconButton to pass the values to the function, because, being in the rule, it has access to them through their ids.

```yaml
…
        MDIconButton:
            ...
            on_press: app.show_popup(title.text, body.text)
```

another way, if your code didn't have access to these ids, from being in a different rule, would be to access them from the app, for that, we must consider:

- You load your kv using Builder.load_string, that returns you a ScreenManager countaining a HomeScreen
- The content of HomeScreen is define in its rule
- You add your ScreenManager to your root widget
- You want to access ids inside the rule for HomeScreen

so in `show_popup` you could get your screen, from the screenmanager, and get the ids from the screen.

```py
def show_popup(self):
    sm = self.root.children[0] # because you put the screenmanager in your root screen
    home_screen = sm.get_screen('home')
    title = home_screen.ids.title.text
    body = home_screen.ids.body.text
    ...
```

This is a bit more work, but it can sometime be convenient to go this way.

Comment: i added that code to my file but I am getting an error: -
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'